# Are there any tools that allow setting up routes using annotations in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, routes, annotations

Being used to Symfony, I wonder if there is a way to set up routes using annotations in nodejs.

For example, let's say I have the following code:

```
/**
 * @Route('/', method="GET")
 */
 var homeAction = function(req, res){


 }
```

And somehow compile it to the following:

```
var router = require('my-actual-router');

var homeAction = function(req, res){

}
router.get('/', homeAction);
```

I have found some npm packages that can be used to parse annotations but not tools that use annotations to generate actual javascript code and I wonder if there is some obscure tool I'm missing before I start writing my own.

Comment: Whats the difference between specifying the route definition in an annotation vs. specifying the one line of code for the actual route definition?  I'm not seeing the advantage here.

Comment: It's part of a bigger thing I'm working on, and one of the things I'm trying to do is decouple configuration from logic.

Comment: Why don't you just define a route table of data in Javascript itself rather than some foreign syntax that needs a different parser.  In your initialization code, you can then loop over the table and create all the desired routes.

Comment: For the same reason I like to use anotations on Symfony: Anotations allow me to keep my configuration together with the code they relate to, while being separate from the logic since they are not code themselves.

Comment: A table of data in Javascript format is technically code (because the Javascript parser will parse it for you), but it's as separated from the code as some structured comments that must be parsed by another parser.  Your configuration would still be separate from the logic.  It's just a table of data that happens to be expressed in a way that the Javascript parser can parse it rather than needing a separate parser for it.  But, if you're stubbornly refusing to use the parser you already have, then I'll go about my way and leave.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, asking for a 3rd party tool is also off-topic on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using a package called routing-controllers to build the expressjs route using annotations. It is pretty good and in general works as expected.

It does however have a requirement that might deter many: it is built using typescript and thus might not be usable out of box on vanilla javascript node projets.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/routing-controllers

Answer (score 0):

I created this package from my production code to do just that:

[image: carbon]

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

What I did in this situation - I replaced the annotation with the check for no arguments like that:

Server setup code:

```
const app = express();
testController.setupForServer(app, "/api/tests");
```

Controller code:

```
let
  path = require('path');

const testsController = {

  setupForServer(expressApp, parentUrl) {
    for(let elementName in this) {
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(elementName)) {
        if (typeof this[elementName] === 'function'){
          if ( elementName.startsWith("get")
            || elementName.startsWith("put")
            || elementName.startsWith("post")
            || elementName.startsWith("delete")) {
            let urlMapping = path.join(parentUrl, this[elementName]());
            if (typeof urlMapping == "string") {
              expressApp.get(urlMapping, (req, res) => {
                return this[elementName](req, res);
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  getAllTests(req, res) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) return "all"; // this will be resolved to <parentUrl>/all
    res.send('hello world from TestsController.getAllTests');
  }
}

module.exports = testsController;
```